# Minimizing discrete vector/array without knowing function?

Tags: python, vector, difference, derivative

I am trying to find the minimum of the second derivative for the elements in the array below:

```
scores = [-100.07, -40.04, -26.97, -17.31, -13.12, -9.02, -7.22,
     -5.23, -4.37, -3.44, -2.92, -2.36, -2.11, -1.78,
     -1.59, -1.37, -1.23, -1.1 , -0.97, -0.87]
```

Plotting these data when `k` is 20 results in the plot below. I've circled in red the "optimal" number of clusters based on this score measure.

[image]

The issue, though, is that I had to manually intervene (i.e. the computer didn't select this point of minimization). I would rather have the computer select the appropriate `k`, so I'm trying to find the point at which the second derivative is smallest.

I have tried differencing, e.g.

```
import numpy as np
first_diff = np.diff(scores, 1)
second_diff = np.diff(scores, 2)
```

But this isn't satisfactory, as the sequence of second differences produces some positive numbers and then some negative numbers, which won't produce the results I want when using `np.argmin`. Using percent changes doesn't work well, either.

Is there a reliable way to difference these types of vectors?

Comment: Fit a curve and use its second derivative?

Comment: It is a classic problem. As Eckles says, fit a curve using an exponential, compute the abscissa/ordinate for which you have a change of convexity, take the point on the original curve the closest to this abscissa/ordinate.